# 2-tree relaxation for traveling salesman problem

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, algorithms

In the STSP i know the 1-tree relaxation procedure:

1. Determine a minimum cost spanning tree on nodes $\{{2, . . . , n}\}$ by using a greedy
   algorithm (Kruskal, Prim,...),
2. select two edges incident in node 1 with smallest cost.

This offer me a lower bound for my problem,in my homework is asked me to apply the 2-tree relaxation,i don't find some explanation on web,and i suppose that i have to find a minimum cost spanning tree on nodes $\{3,..,n\}$ and after select some incident edges on nodes $\{1,2\}$,but i'm not able to understand in which way.